# Is it possible to have both a subquery and a function in a WITH clause?

Tags: oracle, oracle-12c, functions, subquery

In Oracle 12c, we can include [subqueries in the WITH clause](https://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/with-clause):

```
WITH dept_count AS (
  SELECT deptno, COUNT(*) AS dept_count
  FROM   emp
  GROUP BY deptno)
SELECT e.ename AS employee_name,
       dc.dept_count AS emp_dept_count
FROM   emp e
       JOIN dept_count dc ON e.deptno = dc.deptno;
```

We can also include [functions in the WITH clause](https://oracle-base.com/articles/12c/with-clause-enhancements-12cr1):

```
WITH
  FUNCTION with_function(p_id IN NUMBER) RETURN NUMBER IS
  BEGIN
    RETURN p_id;
  END;
SELECT with_function(id)
FROM   t1
WHERE  rownum = 1
```

**Is it possible to include both a subquery and a function in the WITH clause of a single query?**

---

*This is just a hypothetical question that came to mind. I don't have any real-world examples, but would be interested to see how this might work. I'm not really experienced enough to come up with an example that's useful.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an example:

```
with 
  function f1 return number is begin return 1; end;
  t1 as (select * from dual connect by level <= 3)
  select f1 from t1;
  /

        F1
----------
         1
         1
         1
```

Comment: Thanks Balazs. Just a heads up, I posted an answer that is an exact copy of your answer, just formatted differently. I didn't think it was appropriate to nitpick your formatting in the form of an *edit*. So I posted an answer instead.

Comment: The syntax for this is .. horrifying (having to use `;` instead of `,` as separator after the function)

Comment: @ypercubeᵀᴹ `;` is not the sepator, it is part of `end;`. There is no separator for PL/SQL blocks, this is valid as well: `with function f1 return number is begin return 1; end; function f2 return number is begin return 1; end; select f1, f2 from dual;` with a `/` in a new line like above.

Answer (score 1):

As a beginner, it's helpful to see SQL formatted in a traditional way.

Here is @Balazs answer, just spaced out a bit more:

```
with 
  function f1 return number 
    is 
    begin 
    return 1; 
  end;

  t1 as 
  ( select 
        * 
    from 
        dual 
    connect by level <= 3)

select 
    f1 
from 
    t1;
```